# What are principles of building URIs on Android platform?

Tags: android, uri

Is there any documentation on principles behind using URIs on Android platform? For example, I have an application that allows user to read particular forums. It has a couple of activities - one for viewing list of forums, one for viewing list of threads, one for viewing list of posts, etc.

I'd like to use a hierarchical URI in my activities' intents to indicate what an activity should display. Is it a good idea? If so, what is the best way to formulate those URIs?

For example, should I use my own scheme like `myforums:` or `content:` scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use standard http URIs for viewing public web content and set up your intent filter based on the host/path. Some illustrations of this include Android Market, which will open links to apps on http://market.android.com while the site itself will open in any browser. The YouTube app will open direct links to videos as well.

Using http URIs means that shared links to that content may be opened from any browser on any platform if your app is not present, but the app can take over when it's there to provide a richer or more optimized experience.

Comment: Thank you. In what cases it is recommended to add new schemes then?

Comment: Almost never. See RFC 4395 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4395 A lot of software ignores this process, but it cites very practical reasons not to register new schemes, including: "URI schemes constitute a single, global namespace; it is desirable to avoid contention over use of short, mnemonic scheme names.  For these reasons, the unbounded registration of new schemes is harmful.  New URI schemes SHOULD have clear utility to the broad Internet community, beyond that available with already registered URI schemes." Be a good citizen and don't make up new URI schemes for your mobile app. :)

Comment: You should know that this approach is being deprecated (unfortunately). Google is in favor of using "intent://" instead of "http://", which changes the whole concept (as you can't rely on the browser to handle the link if your app is not installed anymore). See https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents . The good thing is that the "intent://" links can contain your app's package, so you app's entry in Google Play will be opened if the app is not installed.

Comment: The idea of handling http:// URIs in an intent handler being deprecated is entirely false. If your app is capable of viewing a representation of the data at a given http URI there is nothing wrong with handling the appropriate intent at all. The page you linked to is relevant if there is an intent you would like to invoke from a page that *only* makes sense in the context of an Android app and does not semantically match the idea of viewing the content at an http URI in a richer context within your app.