# Intent filter with scheme and host does not work

Tags: android

I have a following `intent filter`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="content" android:host="my.company.name" />
</intent-filter>
```

But it does not match the following `Intent`:

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("content").authority("my.company.name").appendPath("names").build()
uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, id1);
uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, "data");

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that you cannot register an activity for the `content` scheme, as that is used by the content provider system.

If your activity really is backed by content providers, use the MIME type for the content instead, such as:

```
<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note" />
```

If this relates to your [other recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084263/what-are-principles-of-building-uris-on-android-platform), you may wish to follow the advice of the Google employee who answered that question. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler) demonstrating this technique, particularly the third `<intent-filter>` in the manifest.

Comment: Then how does it work for showing contact information with `ACTION_VIEW` and uri like `content://contacts/people/1`? Also, yes, that question is related, and I plan to add filters for `http` scheme too, but initially I wanted to implement a usage pattern like that of contacts.

Comment: Disregard previous comment :) Looks like the system asks every registered content provider to determine MIME type of the URI and implicitly adds that information to the intent. So, adding MIME type really solved the problem. Thank you!